# How to add custom field or attribute to customer's address and API and save it in magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento-2.0

I have created my custom field and attribute, using following code and it is reflected in db.

```
$attributesInfo = [
            'state' => [
                'label' => 'State',
                'type' => 'static',
                'input' => 'text',
                'position' => 140,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ],
        ];

        $columns = [
                    'state' => [
                        'type' => Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'LENGTH' =>255,
                        'comment' => 'State',
                    ],
                ];


        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }


        $tableNames=['customer_address_entity','quote_address','sales_order_address'];

          // Declare data

        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
            foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
            }
        }
```

and i created my fieldset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="customer_address">
            <field name="state">            
                <aspect name="create" />
                <aspect name="update" />
                <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_address">
            <field name="state">
                <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
            <field name="state">
                <aspect name="to_order_address" />
                <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
            </field>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="sales_copy_order_billing_address">
            <field name="state">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="order_address">
            <field name="state">
                <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

and then i edited edit.phtml file and added my custom field state

**but after i clicked save address  the data is not saving in db , do i need to do any thing extra to save the data in db ?**

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 2.2

In the case of customer address, saving extension attributes is a little bit different as explained in the documentation of Magento for Product entities. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

The following steps needs to be done:

- Create an `etc/extension_attributes.xml` and define the attribute for the `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`
- Create a `etc/fieldset.xml` file if you wish that your custom attributes will be copied from the checkout shipping address fieldset into the customer address fieldset. This is extra, you don't need it if you don't use the information for the checkout or other areas.
- Create an `UpgradeData.php` script to create the attribute
- Create an `UpgradeSchema.php` if you want to set your attribute as a static. Important here is that the attribute is not a system one, otherwise it won't be recognized internally as a custom attribute and won't be saved.
- Then you need to overwrite and update `edit.phtml` template for the address form

You don't need at all a plugin in this case.

Here are some sample code for the different files explained before

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="my_attribute" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**fieldset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">    
        <fieldset id="customer_address">
            <field name="my_attribute">
                <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

**UpgradeData.php** Create the attribute

```
<?php    
namespace MyNamespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallSchema
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /* @var $customerSetup \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', '<')) {

            $attributesInfo = [
                Data::ATTR_PREFIX . 'my_attribute'  => [
                    'label'    => 'My Attribute',
                    'type'     => 'varchar', // can be static too
                    'input'    => 'text',
                    'position' => 81,
                    'visible'  => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'system'   => 0, // Important otherwise attribute is not seen as custom attribute
                ],
            ];

            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
                $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
            }

            foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {

                $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
                $attribute->setData(
                    'used_in_forms',
                    ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
                );
                $attribute->save();
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

**UpgradeSchema.php** if case you use want a static attribute, update the DB table of customer address

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * Upgrade the Quote module DB scheme
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $connectionName = 'checkout';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $setup->getConnection(self::$connectionName)->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('customer_address', self::$connectionName),
            'my_attribute',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'comment' => 'My attribute'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

**view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml** to insert your own edit.phtml form

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyNamespace_Modulename::address/edit.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml** Template of the address form to improve

```
...
    <div class="field my_attribute">
        <label class="label" for="my_attribute"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Attribute')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="my_attribute"
                   id="my_attribute"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('my_attribute')->getValue()) ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

create the attribute as shown below in community version , if its EE then magento2 default provide add attribute for custom and customer address from admin side and also you can use below code to create custom customer attribute pragmatically in magento2

```
   $attributesInfo = [
        'state' => [
            'label' => 'State',
            'type' => 'static',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 160,              
            'visible' => true,
            'system'=>0,    
            'is_user_defined' => 1,
            'required' => false,
        ],
    ];



    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode)
            ->setData('used_in_forms', ['customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','adminhtml_customer_address'])
            ->save();
    }
```